# DirectShow.Net play video with audio

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, directshow.net

DirectShow.Net contains sample project DxPlay which plays video without audio. I need to modify this project to make it play audio. I have read I need to add an audio filter and connect to pin but I didn't find a way to do it.

Here is the code from the sample that sets filters up:

```
// Add the filters necessary to render the file.  This function will
// work with a number of different file types.
IBaseFilter sourceFilter = null;
hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(FileName, FileName, out sourceFilter);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

// Get the SampleGrabber interface
m_sampGrabber = (ISampleGrabber)new SampleGrabber();
IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = (IBaseFilter)m_sampGrabber;

// Configure the Sample Grabber
ConfigureSampleGrabber(m_sampGrabber);

// Add it to the filter
hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber");
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

// Connect the pieces together, use the default renderer
hr = icgb2.RenderStream(null, null, sourceFilter, baseGrabFlt, null);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

Could you please hint me how I can make it play audio?

Comment: What about another additional`RenderStream` with `MEDIATYPE_Audio` as second argument (`sourceFilter`/`null` as 3rd and the rest are `null`s)?

Comment: @RomanR., added icgb2.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Audio, sourceFilter, null, null) - it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your video is rendered and audio is not, then *additional*

```
icgb2.RenderStream(null, MediaType.Audio, sourceFilter, null, null)
```

will render the audio part.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
icgb2.RenderStream(null, null, lavSplitter, null, null);
```

If there are both video and audio then after building the video part there is still an audio output pin in the splitter. RenderStream will find it and render, inserting audio decoder and renderer automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have lavSplitter. It was an extra line which appeared when I was playing with the code. The real code from the sample is the one without that line.